# How to use HeidelTime temporal tagger inside a Java project?

Tags: java, maven, temporal, heideltime

I would like to automatically identify dates inside a stream of documents and in this sense I would like to use the code provided by the open source project Heideltime, available here (https://code.google.com/p/heideltime/). I have installed the Heideltime kit (not the standalone version) and now I am wondering how can I reference it and call it inside my Java project. I have already added a dependecy to Heideltime inside my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.unihd.dbs</groupId>
        <artifactId>heideltime</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

however I am not sure how to call the classes from this source project into my own project. I am using Maven for both. Anyone who has used it before could maybe give me a suggestion or piece of advice? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

heideltime-kit is itself a Maven project. So, you can add the heideltime-kit project as a dependency. (In Netbeans, right click on Dependencies, --> Add Dependency --> Open Projects (make sure the project is open first) --> HeidelTime)

Then move the config.props file into your project's src/main/resources folder. Set the path to treetagger within config.props.

As far as using the classes goes, you'll want to create an instance of HeidelTimeStandalone (see de.unihd.dbs.heideltime.standalone.HeidelTimeStandalone.java) using POSTagger.TREETAGGER as the posTagger parameter and a hardcoded path to your src/main/resources/config.props file as the configPath parameter.
For example,

```
heidelTime = new HeidelTimeStandalone(Language.ENGLISH,
                                      DocumentType.COLLOQUIAL,
                                      OutputType.TIMEML,
                                      "path/to/config.props",
                                      POSTagger.TREETAGGER, true);
```

Then to use HeidelTime to process text, you can simply call the process function:

```
String result = heidelTime.process(text, date);
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the reply from jgloves, you might be interested to parse the Heideltime result string into a Java object representation. The following code transforms the Uima-XML representation into [Timex3](https://github.com/microth/heideltime/blob/master/src/de/unihd/dbs/uima/types/heideltime/Timex3.java) objects.

```
    HeidelTimeStandalone time = new HeidelTimeStandalone(Language.GERMAN, DocumentType.SCIENTIFIC, OutputType.XMI, "config.props", POSTagger.STANFORDPOSTAGGER);
    String xmiRepresentation = time.process(document, documentCreationTime); //Apply Heideltime and get the XML-UIMA representation     
    JCas cas = jcasFactory.createJCas();

    for(FSIterator<Annotation> it= cas.getAnnotationIndex(Timex3.type).iterator(); it.hasNext(); ){
            System.out.printkn(it.next);
    }
```

Comment: Hey @user3776894, I try to extract the annotations given by HeidelTime on my text but your code doesn't work for me. I tried to add `cas.setDocumentText(xmiRepresentation);` (without success). Indeed there is no link between your xmiRepresentation and you cas... Can you update your answer with a working piece of code or give me some insights? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This library is not in the maven central repository yet. (You can check this in this [search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org/) site.)

To use the library in your project. You should download the JAR file and install it locally. Refer this questions answer: [How to add local jar files in maven project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-in-maven-project) .

Then you can just use the import package and use the functionality in your project.